# Server start much slower in JUnit tests than when starting application

Tags: kotlin, junit

We have JUnit tests that boot up the entire server and then test some functions in the booted server. However this takes a lot longer than when simply booting the server regularly through it's main function, outside of a a junit test. Why could that be?

More concretely, we're using the dropwizard framework with a jetty server. The logs I get after starting within a unit test are

```
INFO  [2022-09-19 15:12:45,985] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @60649ms
```

and the logs I get with a regular application start are

```
INFO  [2022-09-19 15:15:06,887] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @13093ms
```

As you can see, it's around 6 times faster outside of JUnit.

Is there any reason for that? The server spawned in junit isn't 100% identical to the other one but it comes pretty close. I don't see any reason why it should just be that much slower. Is there any "known" reason why this is happening or is it more likely that's something about how we spawn the server in our testing environment?

When trying to find the bottleneck, I couldn't identify one single place that runs slower. It seems that everything is just running slower in the tests.

**Edit:**

An additional information is that I run on an M1 mac. My previous results, where the tests were 6 times slower than the server start, were with `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk11`. However when I switched to the `brew install --cask zulu-jdk11`, now the disparity is much smaller: 18 seconds for test runs, 12 seconds for server starts. It doesn't make the mystery smaller, but it makes me a bit happier.

Comment: Is this when running tests via Gradle/Maven? If so, you may want to take a look at the amount of memory you allocate.

Comment: i had the exact same result when running through intellij (not sure what it does under the hood) or through gradle directly through command line. i'll check the memory allocation.

Comment: so there was actually less memory allocated in the tests, but it didn't affect the outcome when increasing it, the startup speed stayed the same.

Comment: one thing i figured out in the process (which helped me a lot, but doesn't explain the phenomenon yet) is that on M1 macs you should `brew tap mdogan/zulu && brew install --cask zulu-jdk11` and not `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk11`... :)

Comment: Is possible that JDK11 you get with adoptopenjdk11 is not arm64 and so runs with emulation?

Comment: yes, that's what i think too. but it still puzzles me why now the regular server start takes still ~10 seconds, while the server start in the tests takes 20 seconds instead of 60.